# TexView onClickListener not working from Kotlin based activity

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, android-view

I recently switched to kotlin, and created an activity and added few views in it, but the click listener on my `TextView` is not working.

Following is my xml file.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHomeSignIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/signin_curve_allside"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView21"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView21"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.173" />
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class HomeActivityV2 : AppCompatActivity{ 

 lateinit var tvSignIn: TextView
 lateinit var  ivHomeTeam:ImageView
 lateinit var  ivAwayTeam:ImageView


  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_v2)



         tvSignIn= findViewById(R.id.tvHomeSignIn)
         tvSignIn.setOnClickListener(clickListener)

   }


       val clickListener = View.OnClickListener {view ->

           when (view.getId()) {
            R.id.tvHomeSignIn -> launchSignInActivity()
        }
    }


 }
```

Comment: what does not working mean? Please show the real code

Comment: @TimCastelijns nothing happens when i tap on TextView, let me add the complete code

Comment: not the complete code, just the real code. The one you have above doesn't compile

Comment: [No need to do `findViewById()` in kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding)

Comment: Is this code accurate, are you setting the click listener before initialising it?

Comment: @TimCastelijns : I have added updated code,

Comment: @ScottCooper : I also tried, view.SetOnCLickListener{ performAction() }, but it also didn't work

Comment: probably it works and the problem is elsewhere. Check with debugger if the when statement is executed

Comment: @TimCastelijns: I have cordinatorLayout and inside that i have a constriant layout which contains this text view, in the same cordinatorLayout i have multiple `<include> tags` each contains multiple constraint layouts

Comment: yeah so? I repeat "Check with debugger if the when statement is executed"

Comment: Does it got fixed ? @Kirmani88

Comment: @TimCastelijns : no `when` never gets executed, it goes to `val clickListener = View.OnClickListener` when creating activity.

Answer (score 2):

Add the extensions plugin to your build.gradle file so that you don't need to use findViewById anymore.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Then you should be able to add a click listener like so:

```
tvSignIn.setOnClickListener { view ->
    launchSignInActivity()
}
```

Comment: that's just a different way to do it, whatever the issue is, this shouldn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do something like this ->

```
class HomeActivityV2 : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener{ 

 lateinit var tvSignIn: TextView
 lateinit var ivHomeTeam:ImageView
 lateinit var ivAwayTeam:ImageView


  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_v2)

        tvSignIn= findViewById(R.id.tvHomeSignIn)
        tvSignIn.setOnClickListener(clickListener)

   }

  override fun onClick(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {
             R.id.tvHomeSignIn ->launchSignInActivity()
        }
   }

   private fun launchSignInActivity(){
       ///Your intent method over here.
   }
 }
```

Its just same as java but a little different. Check it and let me know about it. Thank you.

Comment: that's just a different way to do it, whatever the issue is, this shouldn't fix it

Comment: what does that mean?